# What is the underlying design pattern behind AOP?

Tags: design-patterns

Had this interesting question being asked today and the arguments varied from Proxy to Wrapper to Decorator.

Thoughts?

Comment: i believe it depends on how you implement the AOP, as fas as I know you can implement it as a constructor injector method, interface injector and setter injector

Comment: According to GoF wrapper is another name for decorator.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The short description of

- *Proxy*: "Provide a surrogate or placeholder for another object to control access to it".*
- *Decorator*: "Attach additional responsibilities to an object dynamically."*
- *Adapter* (Wrapper): "Convert the interface of a class into another interface clients expect."*

Based on this, to me AOP looks like (a solution to the problem solved by) Decorator rather than Proxy - and definitely not Adapter.

*From the GoF book.

Comment: That's what I thought. AOP would amount to attaching additional responsibility to an object dynamically.

Comment: Beautiful and clear summary.
AOP is essentially implementation of Decorator.

Proxy may be cited because the most famous implementation of AOP rely on frameworks who use Proxy at the base, like Spring... however you don't need these frameworks or Proxy pattern to have AOP.

Answer (score 8):

> "the arguments varied from Proxy to Wrapper to Decorator."

Correct.  That's why they give it a new name -- Aspect-Oriented Programming -- not just an OOP design pattern.

If it could be reduced to a single design pattern, it wouldn't last long in the marketplace of ideas.

The point is to take viewpoint that's a bit more broad.